# Is it possible for a digital multimeter to be modified to read 10 times the ac voltage?

Tags: voltage, ac, multimeter

I would like to modify a kit multimeter so the ac voltage can be read ten times larger for teaching purposes. The test bay has been set up on 24 V AC but I want the students to be able to read 240 Volt AC with the modified meter.[image: Block =]

[image: schematic]

Comment: This will be hard as it is usually all in one IC.  You might at best be able to move the decimal point.  Why not incorporate the scaling in the lesson?  There is even a precedent, in high voltage probes which read a fraction of the actual voltage.  Or you could make your own simple meter.

Comment: Believe it or not, your question is unclear! Do you want the meter to be inaccurate (display 240V when the input voltage is really only 24) or do you have a meter rated for 24V max, and you want to use it to accurately read up to 240V?

Comment: @mkeith - no.  There are problems with the idea, but the question is actually quite explicit about what the idea is.  Please re-read.

Comment: Is it possible to move the decimal point someway via the um 7106 microprocessor chip?

Comment: Unlikely.  You'd probably need to cut and reroute the wires driving the decimal points.  But come to think of it, that won't work either as they are certainly multiplexed.  Likely your options are to build a fully custom voltmeter, or teach your students about instruments which need to have their readings multiplied - with heavy computerization of test gear this isn't quite as common as it used to be, but it has historical been a major fact of an engineer's life, and likely will continue to be encountered on occasion.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your input you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transformer to step down the voltage. You can use a transformer with spec Vout/Vin = 10, in which case your multimeter will read 240 volts as 24 volts and 1 volt as 0.1 volt. The resolution will be an issue here, but if you don't need high precision, you can use this method. However, DC level shift will be brought to zero as transformer does not work in case of DC voltages.

Hope this helps.

Mohit

Comment: Excellent suggestion: The kit multimeter may not be 240v-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The [7106](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7106-07-07s.pdf) is a very old voltmeter chip that will drive an LCD display (static drive, not multiplexed) directly.

The AC to DC conversion and decimal point control are both external, as is the ranging, so there is no question that the kit could be modified as you suggest.

If you can supply a proper schematic, I am sure we can help you.

Decimal point is no problem- since this is a 2000 count chip, you will only be able it display 240 VAC with 1V resolution, so no decimal point is required- and disabling any existing one will be trivial.

---

Edit: it appears you wish to fool the meter into reading 10x higher than the actual input voltage. This meter uses a particularly crappy AC-DC conversion method (just a diode rather than a precision rectifier) so it won't be particularly accurate.

I guess if you short the 900 ohm and increase the 100 ohm to 1K that will give you what you want- it will indicate 199.9 full scale in both positions but in the higher position the display will show 240 with 24VAC in. In the lower position it will show 24.0.

Incidentally, don't be confused by the 750V scale- the actual full scale reading would be 1999V (2kV) except they didn't use parts that are safe at that high a voltage (and perhaps not at 750 or 240VAC either, but that's another story). So that explains the 10:1 ratio you see between 100 and 100+900.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35530/spehro-pefhany can you see the schematic?

Comment: I see it now and it is pretty horrifying.

Comment: Sorry about that it is the best one we have. :)

Comment: Jo, welcome to the Electronics SE. Please add any new  information by editing and adding to your original question, and you can add comments below like your one above rather than editing my (or anyone else's answer). Your question is well formed and fits well here.